# Difference between these two phrases

Tags: past-tense, tense-agreement

In one of my essay which was about describing a picture, I've written a sentence about the illustration and said:

> "This photo has been took during the prohibition"

But my brother has told me this sentence isn't correct. Because he was short in time I didn't received any other explications. I'm sure it's the tense that cause the disorder but actually i don't have any idea about how to correct this error.

Are these a correct form of tense that could be use in this sentence ?

> This photo was made
>
> This photo has been took

Answer (score 1):

*This photo was made* is grammatically correct, but a photo is usually described as *shot* or *taken*.

Best:

> This photo was taken

Acceptable:

> This photo was made

Incorrect:

> This photo has been took

You'd use *took* when describing the action of the person with the camera:

> She took the photo

Comment: Your explication has occurred me that my mistake came from direct translation from my native language (French) to English. We usually say

> She has took a photo. 

For next time I am going to be more attentive and avoid this kind of error.

Comment: You can use *She took a photo,* or "She has taken a photo," but not *She has took a photo*.